# Querying Numpy Structured Array Based On Structured Array Within

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, data-science

I've got a structure like the following one:

```
product_type = np.dtype([('message_counter', np.int),
                         ('alteration_time', 'U32'),
                         ('area_states', status_type, (3,)),
                        ])
```

with:

```
status_type = np.dtype([('area', 'U32'),
                        ('state', 'U32')])
```

furthermore I have an array of `product_type` like:

```
products = np.array([product1, product2, ...], dtype=product_type)
```

now I want to select products which only have a `status_type` equal to `('area1', 'active')`. How would I achieve this. I've tried something like:

```
mask = np.isin(products['area_states'][['area', 'state']],
              ('area1', 'active'))
active_products = products[mask]
```

Unfortunately this didn't work out the way I hoped. Of course I only received a mask for the subarray (`status_type`) but I rather like to get a mask on products so that I can filter for the products which only have a `status_type` with `('area1', 'active')`.

so all in all the code would be the following:

```
status_type = np.dtype([('area', 'U32'),
                        ('state', 'U32')])
product_type = np.dtype([('message_counter', np.int),
                         ('alteration_time', 'U32'),
                         ('area_states', status_type, (3,)),
                         ])
products = np.array([(253, '12:00', [('area1', 'active'), ('area2', 'inactive'), ('area3', 'inactive')]),
                     (254, '13:00', [('area1', 'inactive'), ('area2', 'inactive'), ('area3', 'inactive')])],
                    dtype=product_type)
active_products_in_area1 = '???'
```

Comment: It would be great if you included a sample `products` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a target status variable with

```
status = np.array(('area1', 'active'), dtype=status_type)
```

and use `np.any` to get the active products mask (reducing along axis 1 loops through `status_type` list)

```
mask = (products['area_states'] == status).any(axis=1)
active_products_in_area1 = products[mask]
```

which yields only the first record in your sample array:

```
array([(253, '12:00', [('area1', 'active'), ('area2', 'inactive'), ('area3', 'inactive')])],
      dtype=[('message_counter', '<i8'), ('alteration_time', '<U32'), ('area_states', [('area', '<U32'), ('state', '<U32')], (3,))])
```